# English translations of the Maharal's Netzach Yisrael

Tags: translation, maharal

Would anyone know if there are any English translations of the Maharal's Netzach Yisrael?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're looking for a printed version, but sefaria has a community-made translation available here:https://www.sefaria.org/Netzach_Yisrael.1.4?ven=Sefaria_Community_Translation&vhe=Netzach_Yisrael&lang=bi